# Firefox add-on to have tab shortcut like Pale Moon?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I like the way that [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/) manages the tabs. When you press <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>, you don't move to your next (in position) tab but your last opened tab. More importantly (I haven't seen any add-on that covers this feature) when you press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Tab</kbd>, an panel of the thumbnail of the tabs open, and you can type to search for the title for the tabs you want.

Is there an add-on for that?

[image: image description]

Comment: Have you ever tried Ctrl-Tab with Firefox? I can't remember having a special addon for that (unless it's *Tab Mix Plus* having added that feature), but it does both of what you've described: it opens a panel of thumbnails from all your tabs to select from, and if you release it immediately after being pressed, the last used tab is selected. What did I miss? ;)

Comment: It misses the search function :-? The ability to close tab by pressing `W` quite handy, however.

Comment: Ah, OK – I didn't check for that. Maybe you should [edit] your question and explicitly mention what FF covers via Ctrl-Tab, and that you just miss the search?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Clear enough I'd say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any add-on because Firefox already has the capability to search for tabs for years (since at least 2012).

Many people know that typing in the address bar will give you various suggestions including your *currently open tabs*, but few people know that you can specifically tell Firefox to search only opened tabs with `%`. So just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> then type `%` to search

[image: Firefox search tabs from the address bar]

If you have a lot of tabs then there's another way to search them by clicking the *tab overflow* button > Search Tabs

[image: tab overflow search button]

[Mozilla is Making it Easier to Search Open Tabs in Firefox](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/mozilla-is-making-it-easier-to-search-open-tabs-in-firefox/)

---

Similarly you can search in history and bookmark with and `*` respectively just like `%`

> ## Changing results on the fly
>
> If you are looking for a specific type of result, like a bookmark or tag, you can speed up the process of finding it by typing in special characters after each search term in the address bar separated by spaces:
>
> - Add `^` to search for matches in your browsing history.
> - Add `*` to search for matches in your bookmarks.
> - Add `+` to search for matches in pages you've tagged.
> - Add `%` to search for matches in your currently open tabs.
> - Add `#` to search for matches in page titles.
> - Add `$` to search for matches in web addresses (URLs).
> - Add `?` to search for matches in suggestions.

- [Firefox Tip – Search Your Open Tabs](https://blog.mozilla.org/theden/2012/04/30/firefox-tips-search-your-open-tabs/)
- [Awesome Bar - Search your Firefox bookmarks, history and tabs from the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-search-firefox-bookmarks-history-tabs)

---

Besides, Firefox has always had the option to switch to the most recently used tab and show a preview on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of the next tab in order

- [Changing Firefox Tab Cycle Order](https://superuser.com/q/18609/241386)
- [I would like to switch between last used tab, not to iterate through all tabs, is there a shortcut?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1193670)
- [How to Enable Ctrl Tab Cycling in Firefox](https://www.solveyourtech.com/enable-ctrl-tab-cycling-firefox/)

[image: Firefox recently used tab order]